# Calculate probability on a given Dataset (diamonds)

Tags: r, probability

I'm doing R programming question on a data set called `Diamonds`. First of all in order to install and load the data set. Type the following command:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
```

You will get something like this:
[type diamonds(or print diamonds)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jseO.jpg)

Ok now I'm working on a probability question. The question is: *By using this table, calculate the probability that a randomly chosen diamond is of
colour F and VS1 clarity. Give your answer rounded to four decimal places*.

First of all, I created the table of the frequency of the `clarity` (in the rows) and the `colour` (in the
columns) of `diamonds`. I used that command `table(diamonds$clarity, diamonds$color)` to create the table. Here's the screenshot of the table.
[Frequency Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH6wE.jpg)

Now by using this table, I need to  calculate the probability that a randomly chosen diamond is of `colour == F` and `clarity == VS1`.
Rounded to four decimal places.

Can anyone help me with this part of the question? Which function or formula that I need to calculate the probability.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)    
propTable <- round(prop.table(table(diamonds$clarity, diamonds$color)),4)
propTable <- as.data.frame(propTable)
str(propTable)
propTable %>% filter(Var1 == "VS1", Var2 =="F")

  Var1 Var2   Freq
1  VS1    F 0.0253
```

So the answer is 0.0253.

Edit: I unnecessarily complicated it.

```
round(prop.table(table(diamonds$clarity, diamonds$color)),4)["VS1","F"]
```

Comment: Where does `%>%` come from?

Comment: From *dplyr* package. It's called *pipe* operator and it is equivalent to `filter(propTable,Var1 == "VS1", Var2 =="F")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the probability of two independent events A and B that are independent, it is the product of the probabilieties for event A and B:

```
p(A and B) = p(A) * p(B)
```

In your case, it would be the probability of a diamond with clarity VS1:

```
p_clarity_vs1 <- sum(diamonds$clarity == "VS1") / nrow(diamonds)
```

times the probability of a diamond of colour "F":

```
p_color_f <- sum(diamonds$color == "F") / nrow(diamonds)
```

Hence, the probability of clarity VS1 AND color F:

```
p_clarity_vs1 * p_color_f
[1] 0.0267974
```